# Organizing Extensions Functions in a Lib

Tags: c#, extension-methods

In designing a library that is fluent and that relies on extension functions what would be a way to provide an alternative behavior of an extensions function?

So for instance a library that does some kind of formatting:

```
(123.456879)
   .RoundTo(2) // Rounds to 2 places
   .ToCurrency() // Applies the appropriate currency symbol
   .ToString()
```

Given that `RoundTo`, and `ToCurrency` would be extension functions, what would be a way to change the behavior of `RoundTo` and/or `ToCurrency`?

Thanks,
L-

Comment: What do you mean by "changing the behavior"? Could you make an example of what you would like to achieve?

Comment: [Edit] Changed the word Override to 'provide an alternative behavior'

Comment: I'm sorry, I really can't see what you mean with "provide an alternative behavior" either :) Can you make an example? when do you want this "alternative behavior"?

Comment: An example would be to maybe change the behavior of ToCurrency() that changes the output from '$123.45' to '$ 123.45' with a space between the $ and the number.  Which be specific to the clients of this library.

Answer (score 2):

If by overriding you mean having an extension function virtual in a base class and overridden in a derived class, then you cannot - extension functions must be static, and static functions cannot be overridden.

*EDIT*: after your clarification, maybe you could write a [configuration section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx) for the library (or just use the application settings) and have your library read the configuration parameters.

Comment: Right, I changed 'override' to 'provide an alternative behavior' to avoid the normal usage of 'override'.